# ANT installation unsuccessful for Windows7 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ant

I have problem setting up %PATH% for ant. I think I have done it correctly, still it doesn't work from cmd.exe

Here is what `echo %ANT_HOME%` shows

```
C:\Users\Fero>echo %ANT_HOME%
c:\ant
```

and `echo %PATH%`

```
C:\Users\Fero>echo %PATH%
.
.
LLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;"C:\Users\Fero\AppData\Local\Andro
id\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools;%JAVA_HOM
E%\bin;c:\ant\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;
```

and this is actual call for `ant`

```
C:\Users\Fero>ant
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However if I do it manually:

```
C:\Users\Fero>c:\ant\bin\ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
```

There also seems to be additional problem, my `jre` directory has all sorts of .jar files but none called `tools.jar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tools.jar`: it's inside `JDK`, not `JRE`. Please, install jdk and set `JAVA_HOME` to the installation directory.

Also, check you `PATH` environment variable. Two lines with dots look very strange. And there is non-matching quote in path.

And output of `dir %ANT_HOME%` can solve many problems.

Comment: he has added the two dots to show only the relevant part of `PATH`, but 1 up for catching the quote